# What happens here in this capacitor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

What happens when we earth the circuit as shown below, why should it matter? because potential at a point is relative? So if the earlier potential was $V_p$ at that point, it becomes $0$, so every potential becomes $V-V_P$ but the potential difference remains constant, so charge should remain constant and hence no heat should be released. **Please help only in this conceptual doubt.**
[image]

Comment: Hi ADG. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic It says: "any question whose value lies in helping you understand the method by which the question can be solved, rather than getting the answer itself. This includes not just questions from actual homework assignments, but also self-study problems, puzzles, etc.". So maybe you wish to make this a homework question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there were no other absolute voltage references in the problem, then you would be correct.  But there is already a connection to ground on the upper trace of the diagram.  The voltage of that trace does not change (it starts at $0$ and remains $0$ after closing $S$).

Comment: can't get what you mean.

Comment: Do you understand that after closing the switch, the potential of the uppermost trace on the diagram (between the capacitors) does not change?

Comment: yes, so how does it matter?

Comment: You said in your question that every potential becomes $V - V_p$.  But that's incorrect.  Some potentials change (like that of the middle trace), while others do not (like the top trace).  That means the potential between the top and middle trace does not stay constant.

Comment: Oh that's it. Side Question: Isn't it like joining those two points by a conducting wire?

Comment: No, not identical.  Instead it's like joining them with a very large capacitor.  If you joined them by a wire, any charge leaving one trace would have to be added to the other.  By grounding both, the charges are independent.